# MapboxGL Mapbox streets v7 street layer name

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-studio

See this example: 
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/color-switcher/

It styles the water layer and building layer with different colors. I was wondering is there a layer for the "streets" in the mapbox streets v7 map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mapbox Streets style has many road layers (styled differently based on road classification, etc). If you have a Mapbox Studio account, you can go to that style's page (https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/mapbox/streets-v7/ — though if you're interested in the most up-to-date streets style, it's currently v10) and scroll to see the `road` group containing the IDs of all road-related layers:
[image: mapbox-streets-v7 road group]